# Escape elasticsearch special characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, elasticsearch

I want to create a function that escapes elasticsearch special characters by adding a \ before the characters in PHP. The special chars that Elasticsearch use are:
+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

I'm not very familliar with regex, but I have found a piece of code that simply removes the special chars, but i prefer to escape them, because the might be relevant. The code i use:

```
$s_input = 'The next chars should be escaped: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / Did it work?';
$search_query = preg_replace('/(\+|\-|\=|\&|\||\!|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\^|\"|\~|\*|\<|\>|\?|\:|\\\\)/', '', $s_input);
```

This outputs:

```
The next chars should be escaped / Did it work
```

So there are two problems: this code removes the special chars, while i want to escape them with a `\`. Furthermore: this code doesn't escape the `\`. Does anyone know how to escape the Elasticsearch special characters?

Comment: I would recommend reading what the purpose of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is. I only see an empty string in your code above for the replacement argument.

Comment: Yes, but when i place a \ or double \\ in the replace string, it still doesn't work. Sorry, i should have mentioned this in my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with **backreferences** as stribizhev has noticed it (simpliest way) :

```php
$string = "The next chars should be escaped: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \ / Did it work?"; 

function escapeElasticReservedChars($string) {
    $regex = "/[\\+\\-\\=\\&\\|\\!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^\\\"\\~\\*\\<\\>\\?\\:\\\\\\/]/";
    return preg_replace($regex, addslashes('\\$0'), $string);
}
echo escapeElasticReservedChars($string);
```

or use [preg_match_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to achieve that. Thank to the callback, you will be able to have the current match and edit it.

> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements
>   in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement
>   string. This is the callback signature:

Here is in action :

```
<?php 
$string = "The next chars should be escaped: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \ / Did it work?"; 

function escapeElasticSearchReservedChars($string) {
    $regex = "/[\\+\\-\\=\\&\\|\\!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^\\\"\\~\\*\\<\\>\\?\\:\\\\\\/]/";
    $string = preg_replace_callback ($regex, 
        function ($matches) { 
            return "\\" . $matches[0]; 
        }, $string); 
    return $string;
}
echo escapeElasticSearchReservedChars($string);
```

Output: `The next chars should be escaped\: \+ \- \= \&\& \|\| \> \< \! \( \) \{ \} \[ \] \^ \" \~ \* \? \: \\ \/ Did it work\?`

Comment: Backreferences are better than preg_replace_callback. You overcomplicated the solution.

Comment: i agree with you about the simplicity but when you say "better", do you talk about performance? I updated my answer :) TY

Comment: should be $regex = '/[\\+\-\\=\\&\\|\\!\\(\\)\\{\\}\[\]\\^\\\"\\~\\*\\<\\>\\?\\:\\\\\\/]/', i think you do small mistake, because symbols  [,],- have double \\,

Comment: If someone is going to implement this, just keep in mind

[< and > can’t be escaped at all. The only way to prevent them from attempting to create a range query is to remove them from the query string entirely](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Comment: Why all the backslashes in the regex string? For example, instead of starting with `"/[\\+\\-\\=\\&\\|\\!` the regex could start with just `"/[-+=&|!` because none of those is a regex meta character in chacter classes. All the characters in that list can be used as is (however, the dash must be the first or last character in the list).

Comment: Note that this answer is incorrect because it fails to correct handle `<` and `>`.

Comment: I have never used elasticsearch, but I'm pretty sure that this answer is wrong/flawed.  If `&&` is supposed to become `\\&&`, then this pattern fails to recognise doubled symbols like `&&`, and `||`.  Should I also assume that a single ampersand or pipe should NOT be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's looking for a slightly verbose (but readable!) solution:

```
public function escapeElasticsearchValue($searchValue)
{
    $searchValue = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('*', '\\*', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('?', '\\?', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('+', '\\+', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('-', '\\-', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('&&', '\\&&', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('||', '\\||', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('!', '\\!', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('(', '\\(', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace(')', '\\)', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('{', '\\{', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('}', '\\}', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('[', '\\[', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace(']', '\\]', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('^', '\\^', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('~', '\\~', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace(':', '\\:', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('"', '\\"', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('=', '\\=', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('/', '\\/', $searchValue);

    // < and > can’t be escaped at all. The only way to prevent them from
    // attempting to create a range query is to remove them from the query
    // string entirely
    $searchValue = str_replace('<', '', $searchValue);
    $searchValue = str_replace('>', '', $searchValue);

    return $searchValue;
}
```

Comment: `str_replace()` accepts arrays for the first and second parameters.  I would not use or recommend this answer.  This makes, what, ~20 passes over the same input string? Just make one pass with regex and spare the script bloat.

Comment: @mickmackusa have you actually *measured* if `preg_replace()` is cheaper than doing 20 passes with str_replace()? PCRE functions are not exactly cheap.

Comment: If you doubt my advice, you are welcome to set up a benchmark to be reviewed.  My point is about directness.  A single regex pattern can make matches in a single pass; `str_replace()` cannot, it will do full scans for each replacement.  In my opinion, there are too many variables to attempt a benchmark test.

Comment: I will agree that PCRE functions are not cheap, but in some cases they blow away alternatives that make lots of function calls.  Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595575/2943403

Answer (score 1):

This version should be considered deprecated because https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393421/334451 has better performance and produces correct output.

It seems that none of the given answers actually follow the documentation so here's an another one that correctly encodes any untrusted input:

```
/**
 * @param string $s untrusted user input
 * @return string safe string to be used in `query_string` argument to elasticsearch
 */
function escapeForElasticSearch($s)
{
    static $keys = array();
    static $values = array();
    if (!$keys)
    {
        # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters
        $replacements = array(
            ">" => "", # cannot be safely encoded
            "<" => "", # cannot be safely encoded
            "\\" => "\\\\", # must be done first to not double encode later backslashes!
            "+" => "\\+",
            "-" => "\\-",
            "=" => "\\=",
            "&" => "\\&",
            "|" => "\\|",
            "!" => "\\!",
            "(" => "\\(",
            ")" => "\\)",
            "{" => "\\{",
            "}" => "\\}",
            "[" => "\\[",
            "]" => "\\]",
            "^" => "\\^",
            "\"" => "\\\"",
            "~" => "\\~",
            "*" => "\\*",
            "?" => "\\?",
            ":" => "\\:",
            "/" => "\\/",
        );
        $keys = array_keys($replacements);
        $values = array_values($replacements);
    }
    return str_replace($keys, $values, $s);
}
```

Note that `&` or `|` are not special alone but to correctly handle uneven number of those characters would be harder than just encoding every instance of those chacters.

Note that it's important to first remove all characters that must be removed. Otherwise attacker could use sequence that removes characters in the middle of the string after it has already been partially encoded.

Comment: Note that the official documentation doesn't say if control characters (U+0000 ... U+001F) or an out of place low or high surrogate cause problems. It might be a good idea to remove those if you expect binary input.

Comment: I don't think `array_values()` is beneficial.  So that researchers understand, this script makes 22 separate full scans over the onput string.

Comment: I updated the code not to call array_keys() or array_values() in a loop and now this has the same performance as the best non-readable code on the another question. I put simple benchmark script at https://gist.github.com/mikkorantalainen/1a913bb9b3410f3274a062a5390e07b5 so you can see that preg_match() is indeed pretty expensive. It really doesn't matter if you do full scans over the string in this implementation. Do you agree that this is easier to maintain than the regex implementation?

Comment: I don't endorse the accepted answer.  I ran your benchmark and included my own script (which behaves slightly differently) and the performance differences are similar enough to disregard in my opinion.  https://3v4l.org/5KR7n  `(1) Looping 200000 calls took 1.07 s
(2) Looping 200000 calls took 1.64 s
(3) Looping 200000 calls took 1.12 s`

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I've never used elasticsearch and my advice is not from personal experience or even tested with elasticsearch.  I am generating this advice from my knowledge of regular expressions and string manipulation skills.  If someone identifies a vulnerability, I'll be happy to receive your comment.

My snippet:

- first removes all occurrences of `<` and `>` in the string then
- checks for a character in the list of single-occurrence reserved characters OR an ampersand or pipe which is immediately followed by the same character -- all of these qualifying characters are escaped with a backslash.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qa43R))

```
$string = "To be escaped: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \ / triple ||| and split '&<&'"; 

echo escapeElasticSearchReservedChars($string);

function escapeElasticSearchReservedChars(string $string): string
{
    return preg_replace(
        [
            '_[<>]+_',
            '_[-+=!(){}[\]^"~*?:\\/\\\\]|&(?=&)|\|(?=\|)_',
        ],
        [
            '',
            '\\\\$0',
        ],
        $string
    );
}
```

Output:

```
To be escaped\: \+ \- \= \&& \||   \! \( \) \{ \} \[ \] \^ \" \~ \* \? \: \\ \/ triple \|\|| and split '\&&'
```

The reason that `<` and `>` are removed first is so that someone cannot try to hack the design of the replacement and try to pass in `|>|` which otherwise would prevent the appropriate escaping of two consecutive pipes (after the `>` was removed).

Comment: Nice work! I did some additional benchmarking and it seems that this implementation has the highest performance with PHP 8: https://3v4l.org/9F0Pk – older versions might benefit from removing `<` and `>` so that preg_replace() doesn't need to be passed arrays. PHP 8 seems to have faster PCRE initialization than older versions.

Comment: Also note that Elasticsearch (ES) has two different query types. This answer is the correct encoding for ES "query string" but ES "simple query string" requires totally different encoding!

Comment: I will have to trust you on that.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: "Simple query string" syntax: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-syntax
vs "Query string" syntax: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use a single character class to match.
The only question is what to use as a delimiter (for readability).

Using `@` as the regex delimiter, its

Find:  `'@[-+=&|><!(){}[\]^"~*?:\\\/]@'`
Replace:  `'\\$0'`

---

But, what if the actual character is already escaped?
What then?

A solution there is to find those that are *Not* escaped.

Find:  `'@(?<!\\\)(?:\\\\\\\)*\K(?:[-+=&|><!(){}[\]^"~*?:/]|\\\(?!\\\))@'`
Replace: `'\\$0'`

Formatted:

```
 (?<! \\ )                     # Not an escape behind 
 (?: \\ \\ )*                  # Possible even number of escapeds
 \K                            # Don't include the previous escapes in match
 (?:
      [-+=&|><!(){}[\]^"~*?:/]      # Either 1 of these special characters
   |                              # or,
      \\                            # An escape character that is
      (?! \\ )                      # not followed by escape itself.
 )
```