# Validate A Game Board, And Fast

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am creating a multiplayer Battleship game using an Apache/PHP server (yes, I know Node would be much better for this, but I'll get around to learning it later). Anyways, I am at the point in which both players are uploading their game boards to start the game. While my client side JavaScript would obviously properly compile and validate boards before sending them off to the server, that is still vulnerable to cheating, so the server must also double check. However, on the server, speed and efficiency is everything.

As of now, this is the process my server follows:

1. Server receives the board as a JSON encoded multidimensional array via an AJAX request.

   ```
   $board = json_decode($_REQUEST["board"]);
   ```
2. Server validates the structure of the passed input.

   ```
   $validate = array(gettype($board) == "array", count($board) == 10);
   for($i = 0; $i < count($board); $i++) {
      array_push($validate, count($board[$i]) == 10);
      for($ii = 0; $ii < count($board[$i]); $ii++) {
          array_push($validate, gettype($board[$i][$ii]) == "integer");
      }
   }
   if(in_array(0, $validate)) throwError();
   ```
3. In the array, numbers zero through five represent blank, aircraft carrier, battleship, cruiser, submarine, and destroyer tiles respectively. I count the proper quantity of each.

   ```
    $valueCount = array_count_values(array_merge($board[0], $board[1], $board[2], $board[3], $board[4], $board[5], $board[6], $board[7], $board[8], $board[9]));
    $template = array("0"=>83,"1"=>5, "2"=>4, "3"=>3, "4"=>3, "5"=>2);
    if($template != $valueCount) throwError();
   ```
4. I need to ensure that ship tiles are only vertical or horizontal lines.

   ```
    $shipsValid = array(false, false, false, false, false);
    $transpose = array_map(null, $board[0], $board[1], $board[2], $board[3], $board[4], $board[5], $board[6], $board[7], $board[8], $board[9]);
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $temp1 = array_count_values($board[$i]);
        $temp2 = array_count_values($transpose[$i]);
        if($temp1["1"] == 5 || $temp2["1"] == 5) shipsValid[0] = true;
        if($temp1["2"] == 4 || $temp2["2"] == 4) shipsValid[1] = true;
        if($temp1["3"] == 3 || $temp2["3"] == 3) shipsValid[2] = true;
        if($temp1["4"] == 3 || $temp2["4"] == 3) shipsValid[3] = true;
        if($temp1["5"] == 2 || $temp2["5"] == 2) shipsValid[4] = true;
    }
    if(in_array(0, $shipsValid)) throwError();
   ```
5. I need to ensure ships are continuous with no gaps.

   ```
   ??????????????????????????
   ```

With enough work, I could have completed step five, but it would have been grossly inefficient, looping through everything repeatedly. So, in conclusion, how can I make what I have designed more efficient, and how I complete the final step (5) to validating the uploaded board?

Example Board (Valid):

```
    "[[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,3,3,3,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,5,0,0,0,4,4,4,0],
    [0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]"
```

Example Board (Invalid, for many reasons):

```
    "[[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
    [0,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]"
```

Comment: Why not rather send the positions of the ships and not the board? Would be so much easier to handle.

Comment: Such as start and end coordinates of each ship? Yes, that would be simpler for validation here but harder to package client side (with my layout) and harder for MySQL to validate hits/misses during the game.

Comment: For example, or start and angle. Then you can easily just check the amounts are ok, they don’t go outside the board and they don’t overlap (for example by creating the board from that data and seeing nothing is put twice in one hole).

Comment: Can we see some sample input (json)?

Comment: @mickmackusa I have valid and invalid sample input added to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Version 2: Now with the highest priority on speed of validation.

(no `json_decode()` call needed)

The following are my two valid test `$board` strings.  Between the two of them, all ships occur in both orientations.

Test #1:

```
[[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,3,3,3,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,5,0,0,0,4,4,4,0],[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Test #2:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,5,5,0,0,4,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0]]
```

The method to follow is a simple `preg_match()` call in php.  The technique uses  lookaheads to validate each ship, followed by a fullstring match that validates the json structure.

This technique is most commonly used when validating passwords, where a string must be generally validated for length and/or valid characters, but also checked for minimum occurrences of characters or ranges of characters (e.g. password must be a minimum of 8 characters and include a lowercase, uppercase, number, and a symbol).

The brilliance in my method is not just that it is a single call, but that it can also be seamlessly called to validate the data in javascript as well.

Now for the patterns (seatbelts on, please):

## Pattern #1: "**Longer but Faster**"

(1590 characters) ([Test#1: 371 steps](https://regex101.com/r/4dajSg/2); [Test#2 446 steps](https://regex101.com/r/vY3k2Q/2))

`/(?=^[^1]*(?:1,1,1,1,1|1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1)[^1]*$)(?=^[^2]*(?:2,2,2,2|2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2)[^2]*$)(?=^[^3]*(?:3,3,3|3\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+3\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+3)[^3]*$)(?=^[^4]*(?:4,4,4|4\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+4\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+4)[^4]*$)(?=^[^5]*(?:5,5|5\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+5)[^5]*$)^\[\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\]\]$/`

## Pattern #2: "Shorter but Slower"

(306 characters) ([Test#1: 576 steps](https://regex101.com/r/4dajSg/1); [Test#2 698 steps](https://regex101.com/r/vY3k2Q/1))

`/(?=^[^1]*(?:1,1,1,1,1|1(?:(?:\D+[^1]){9}\D+1){4})[^1]*$)(?=^[^2]*(?:2,2,2,2|2(?:(?:\D+[^2]){9}\D+2){3})[^2]*$)(?=^[^3]*(?:3,3,3|3(?:(?:\D+[^3]){9}\D+3){2})[^3]*$)(?=^[^4]*(?:4,4,4|4(?:(?:\D+[^4]){9}\D+4){2})[^4]*$)(?=^[^5]*(?:5,5|5(?:\D+[^5]){9}\D+5)[^5]*$)(?:(?:^\[|)\[[0-5](?:,[0-5]){9}\](?:,|\]$)){10}/`

---

#### The 4 pillars of a good regex pattern...

The reason the first pattern is faster is because I have removed all inessential non-capture groups.  The cost, in terms of "Brevity", is drastic.  "Readability"  is extremely poor in both of patterns.  Both patterns maintain the same "Accuracy", but the first pattern wins on "Efficiency" by some margin.

#### As for the pattern components...

All lookaheads have the same basic structure and obey the game rules/requirements:

```
(?=           #lookahead, but don't "consume" any characters in the process
^             #from the start of the string
[^5]*         #quickly, greedily match all characters that are not a 5
(?:           #non-capture group to isolate the "alternatives"
    5,5       #literally match a 2-peg row
    |         # or
    5\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+5  #match two 5 pegs that have nine non-5 pegs between them
)             #end non-capture group
[^5]*         #quickly, greedily match all characters that are not a 5 (ensure there are no more 5's in the string) 
$             #all the way to the end of the string
)             #end the lookahead
```

The general board structure & pegs matching:

```
^                       #from the start of the string
\[                      #match the opening outer bracket
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's 
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\]  #match a row of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5's
\]                      #match the closing outer bracket
$                       #to the end of the string
```

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/845502f3d36c5a0fb2bd1a3fac714db1bec087c8))

```
$pattern='/(?=^[^1]*(?:1,1,1,1,1|1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+[^1]\D+1)[^1]*$)(?=^[^2]*(?:2,2,2,2|2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+[^2]\D+2)[^2]*$)(?=^[^3]*(?:3,3,3|3\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+3\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+[^3]\D+3)[^3]*$)(?=^[^4]*(?:4,4,4|4\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+4\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+[^4]\D+4)[^4]*$)(?=^[^5]*(?:5,5|5\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+[^5]\D+5)[^5]*$)^\[\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\],\[[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5],[0-5]\]\]$/';
echo preg_match($pattern,$_REQUEST["board"]) ? 'success' : 'invalid';
```

Comment: @BenjaminBrownlee I am interested to hear how this method compares for speed on your server/environment.

Comment: Wow this is really amazing. I would never have thought of keeping the input JSON encoded and preforming a regex. Pretty slick but immensely confusing to look at. I will test this out as soon as I get home.

Comment: To make speed tests comparable, I reran my code including the segment in which I decode the JSON. My code now clocked in at 91.30681038 µs, but your's surpassed mine with flying colors, attaining an average speed of 6.2988114356995 µs per a board validation.

Comment: 5 years later, I still love this page/challenge!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is ugly and not clearly explained inline, but it does set the time record here with an average of 47.99473047 µs to validate a correct board on my server. I do apologize for the excessive use of inline logic structures; its kinda my coding style.

```
function quit() {
    echo "invalid request";
    exit();
}

$board = json_decode($_REQUEST["board"]);
if(gettype($board) != "array"|| count($board) != 10) quit();
foreach($board as $row) {
   if(gettype($row) != "array"|| count($row) != 10) quit();
   foreach($row as $cell) if(gettype($cell) != "integer") quit();
}
$strand = array_merge($board[0], $board[1], $board[2], $board[3], $board[4], $board[5], $board[6], $board[7], $board[8], $board[9]);
$fleet = array(array_keys($strand, 0), array_keys($strand, 1), array_keys($strand, 2), array_keys($strand, 3), array_keys($strand, 4), array_keys($strand, 5));
if(count($fleet[0]) != 83 || count($fleet[1]) != 5 || count($fleet[2]) != 4 || count($fleet[3]) != 3 || count($fleet[4]) != 3 || count($fleet[5]) != 2 || count($fleet) != 6) quit();
foreach($fleet as $ship) if($ship != $fleet[0]) for($i = 0; $i < count($ship); $i++) if($ship[0] + 10 * $i != $ship[$i]  && $ship[$i] - $ship[0] != $i) quit();

echo "success";
exit();
```

This process first checks that the array is properly structured (10 by 10 with integer values). It then combines all the arrays into one long array and fetches the keys of the values 0 through 5. I then check that the proper amount of each number (for each ship) occurs in the keys. Lastly, I check that keys for 1 through 5 occur sequentially or by tens, which would mean that they are horizontal or vertical.

It feels kinda weird answering my own question, but I'm open to other ideas and optimizations on top of my own.