# A quicker PHP regex test

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex, preg-match

I need to sanitize incoming JSON that typically bears the form

```
'["P4950Zp550","P4950Zp575","P4950Zp600","P5000Zp550","P5000Zp575","P5000Zp600","P4975Zp550","P4975Zp600"]'
```

with the number of digits following each `P|M`, `p|m` varying between 3 and 5.  `json_decoding` this and then applying the test

```
preg_match('/(P|M){1}[0-9]{3,5}Z(p|m){1}[0-9]{3,5}/',$value)
```

eight times, in a `foreach` loop,  (I always have eight values in the array) would be a trivial matter.  However, I am wondering if there might not be a Regex I could write that could do this in a oner without me having to first `json_decode` in the incoming string.  My knowledge of RegExs is at its limits with the regex I have created here.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying do to. What is your real data? give a more real world sample input.

Comment: It's best to decode JSON than try to parse the original text. There might be escaping that you can't deal with easily.

Comment: BTW,you can use `[PM]` instead of `(P|M)` and `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. And you don't need to write `{1}`, everything matches exactly once unless you add a quantifier.

Comment: You should also add `^` and `$` anchors so you match the whole string.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop to apply the regexp on each element of the array, instead of writing it 8 times.

Comment: @Barmar when I wrote 8 times I did in fact mean run the test in a loop.  I have edited the question to reflect that.  Thank you for confirming that it would be better to `json_decode` and then operate on the individual array elements.

Comment: Downvoter would you care to explain what forum rules I have broken, what lack of own effort I have displayed, what nature of self publicity I have engaged in...?  Or indeed any other reason why you chose to downvote and close.

Comment: Downvoters don't generally stick around to answer. It's probably just because they thought the question was unclear.

Comment: @DroidOS May be it is because he finds your question lacks in clarity. Well, I also find certain areas of this a little vague..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly, deeply want to validate the 8-element array in a single pass while it is still a json string, you can use this:

Pattern: `~^\["[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm]\d{3,5}(?:","[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm]\d{3,5}){7}"]$~`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/90r8kR/1) -- this matches the first, then the seven to follow; all wrapped appropriately.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LEZPa))

```
$string = '["P4950Zp550","P4950Zp575","P4950Zp600","P5000Zp550","P5000Zp575","P5000Zp600","P4975Zp550","P4975Zp600"]';

if (preg_match('~^\["[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm]\d{3,5}(?:","[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm]\d{3,5}){7}"]$~', $string)) {
    echo "pass";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
// outputs: pass
```

Sometimes, you just want to bulk validate input [:]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595575/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Decode the JSON and then use a loop:

```
$json = '["P4950Zp550","P4950Zp,575","P4950Zp600","P5000Zp550","P5000Zp,575","P5000Zp600","P4975Zp550","P4975Zp600"]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm]\d{3,5}$/',$value)) {
        echo "Invalid value: $value<br>\n";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/weSxlJ)

Trying to parse the original JSON with a regexp is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
(\"[PM]\d{3,5}Z[pm](\,)?\d{3,5}\"(\,)?)*
```

Here, the expression is enclosed in `()*` which groups the inner expression and looks for any number of occurrences (`*`) of the inner group. You can include the square brackets also if you prefer...

Comment: Why do you have `(\,)?` in the regexp? The items with the commas don't follow the pattern he described, they're not supposed to pass validation.

Comment: That's then the lack of clarity of his questioning style. :) You can then take it you and you should be all good. Shall I take it out?