# PHP regular expression: Match a whole expression a number of times inside another expression

Tags: php, regex

### **SUMMARY**

Sample string to match:

> **BEFORE *Test1* *Test2* *Test3* AFTER**

Regular Expression needed:

> **BEFORE *(expression)* AFTER**

---

### **DETAILED EXPLANATION**

I have a problem with regular expressions in PHP and even after extensive searches and countless tries I am still unable to get it right and it's quite infuriating.

This is the string I want to analyse:

> "places":[{"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"},{"id":1205,"name":"Room
>   2"},{"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"},{"id":1207,"name":"Room
>   4"},{"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"},{"id":1209,"name":"Room
>   6"},{"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"},{"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}]

Formatted for better readability

```
"places":[
  {
    "id":1204,
    "name":"Room 1"
  },
  {
    "id":1205,
    "name":"Room 2"
  },
  {
    "id":1206,
    "name":"Room 3"
  },
  {
    "id":1207,
    "name":"Room 4"
  },
  {
    "id":1208,
    "name":"Room 5"
  },
  {
    "id":1209,
    "name":"Room 6"
  },
  {
    "id":1210,
    "name":"Room 7"
  },
  {
    "id":1211,
    "name":"Room 1"
  }
]
```

The result when using **preg_match_all** should be the following array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => {"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"}
    [1] => {"id":1205,"name":"Room 2"}
    [2] => {"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"}
    [3] => {"id":1207,"name":"Room 4"}
    [4] => {"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"}
    [5] => {"id":1209,"name":"Room 6"}
    [6] => {"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"}
    [7] => {"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => 1204
    [1] => 1205
    [2] => 1206
    [3] => 1207
    [4] => 1208
    [5] => 1209
    [6] => 1210
    [7] => 1211
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    [0] => Room 1
    [1] => Room 2
    [2] => Room 3
    [3] => Room 4
    [4] => Room 5
    [5] => Room 6
    [6] => Room 7
    [7] => Room 1
   )
)
```

Right now I use **preg_match_all** two times in a row like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\"places\"\:\[(.*)\]/', $places_string, $raw_string_to_analyse);
```

Now I have the middle part:

> {"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"},{"id":1205,"name":"Room
>   2"},{"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"},{"id":1207,"name":"Room
>   4"},{"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"},{"id":1209,"name":"Room
>   6"},{"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"},{"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}

Now I'm extracting the info like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\"id\"\:([0-9]*),\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\"\}/', $places, $middle_part);
```

And now I have the information I need.

Unfortunately I'm unable to combine these two expressions into one expression like this:

> **[MATCH_BEFORE] *[MATCH_IN_THE_MIDDLE]{as often as necessary}* [MATCH_AFTER]**

So I have to replace the **(.*)*** from the first expression with **{\"id\":([0-9]),\"name\":\"(.*?)\"},?**
*(Notice the optional comma at the end)*

I was unable to find a way to enclose the inner expression into brackets (or whatever is needed) and let it match a certain number of times (*).

I hope someone is able to help me, because right now I'm pretty aggravated that I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: why don't you use json_decode to get an array or object that will be way easier to process ?

Comment: I'll use json_decode for this particular problem now, but I still need to know how to put a regular expression inside another regular expression to be matched an unknown number of times, since I have other (non-json) strings to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is actually an json string. That being said you only need to decode it and do some data extraction on the result:

```
$string = '{"places":[{"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"},{"id":1205,"name":"Room 2"},{"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"},{"id":1207,"name":"Room 4"},{"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"},{"id":1209,"name":"Room 6"},{"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"},{"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}]}';

$data = json_decode($string, true);
$ids = array_column($data['places'], 'id');
$names = array_column($data['places'], 'name');
```

*Later edit*

Well, to achieve the same results but with regex, the only regular expression you may use would be `/{"id":([0-9]+),"name":"([\w\s]+)"}/`. The matches would be exactly those which you expected in the question:

```
preg_match_all('/{"id":([0-9]+),"name":"([\w\s]+)"}/', $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result would be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"}"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1205,"name":"Room 2"}"
    [2]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"}"
    [3]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1207,"name":"Room 4"}"
    [4]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"}"
    [5]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1209,"name":"Room 6"}"
    [6]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"}"
    [7]=>
    string(27) "{"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1204"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1205"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1206"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "1207"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "1208"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "1209"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "1210"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "1211"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Room 1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Room 2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Room 3"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Room 4"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Room 5"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "Room 6"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "Room 7"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "Room 1"
  }
}
```

If you have multiple keys and you only need to match only for places then you first must extract all the places values and do the preg_match_all on the result:

```
preg_match('/(?<=places"\:\[).*?(?=\])/', $string, $match);
preg_match_all('/{"id":([0-9]+),"name":"([\w\s]+)"}/', $match[0], $matches);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's actually quite easier than I thought it would be. I'll be using it this way now. However I'm still interested in how to put a regular expression inside another regular expression to be matched an unknown number of times, since I have to deal with that quite a lot and was not able to find a solution so far.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have multiple "groups" that contain "id" and "name" not just "places". How do I just select the "places" and leave the others out?

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I'll have to do it in two separate matches like you did in your second edit. I think it's pretty sad that it's not possible to combine them into one big match, that would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me announce, categorically, that **you should not abuse a valid json string by attempting to parse its values with regex** ...[unless you have a seriously compelling reason to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595575/2943403)

Matei's solution involving `json_decode()` and `array_column()` is exactly how I would write my code and should be how you write yours because it is direct and employs best practice (assuming the json is valid).

As for your theoretical / unposted data that is *not* json but you wish to perform a global repeated match... yes, you can perform a single, clever regex function call by leveraging the magic of `\G`.

Some documentation to help understand how to continue matching repeating sequences. https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UIPqXz/1) (using your json data)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DONrW))

```
$json = <<<JSON
{"places":[{"id":1204,"name":"Room 1"},{"id":1205,"name":"Room 2"},{"id":1206,"name":"Room 3"},{"id":1207,"name":"Room 4"},{"id":1208,"name":"Room 5"},{"id":1209,"name":"Room 6"},{"id":1210,"name":"Room 7"},{"id":1211,"name":"Room 1"}]}
JSON;

if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G,|\{"places":\[)\K\{"id":(\d+),"name":"([^"]+)"}~', $json, $matches)) {
    unset($matches[0]);  // throw away the fullstring matches subarray
    var_export($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1204',
    1 => '1205',
    2 => '1206',
    3 => '1207',
    4 => '1208',
    5 => '1209',
    6 => '1210',
    7 => '1211',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Room 1',
    1 => 'Room 2',
    2 => 'Room 3',
    3 => 'Room 4',
    4 => 'Room 5',
    5 => 'Room 6',
    6 => 'Room 7',
    7 => 'Room 1',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the examples. It seems like I need to think a little more outside the box from now on.

Comment: Fewer developers know about the `\G` character in regex.  As I said before, you shouldn't use this on your valid json.  This pattern is definitely unnecessary convolution.  It should only be a consideration when your string is not json.  Happy to help.

Comment: Since it didn't come to me as a JSON file I didn't even think about parsing it that way. In the future I will take a step back and look a little bit to the side to find other solutions.