# How to change the color of the winning tic tac toe squares in php?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, background-color

I have a tic tac toe game in PHP that uses an array of three arrays and displays the winner (or tie) upon completion. There's a play again button that also resets the board.

How can I make it so the winning squares are highlighted in a different color?

```php
<?php

// Using MVC, the MODEL is our data for the game..
//$_SESSION = []; session_destroy(); exit();
//unset($_SESSION); session_destroy(); exit();
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
define("X", "X");
define("O", "O");
define("SPACE", " ");
define("NOWIN", "");
$msg = "Tic Tac Toe";
$winner = NOWIN;
if (!isset($_SESSION['board'])) {
    // first time in game..
    $_SESSION['board'] = array(array(" "," "," "),
                               array(" "," "," "),
                               array(" "," "," "));
    $_SESSION['player'] = 'X';
    $_SESSION['moves'] = 0;
} else if (isset($_GET['reset'])) {
    // play new game..
    session_destroy();
    // $_SESSION = [];
    $_SESSION['board'] = [ [" "," "," "], [" "," "," "], [" "," "," "] ];
    $_SESSION['player'] = 'X';
    $_SESSION['moves'] = 0;
} else {
    // CONTROLLER logic continues playing..
    $val = $_SESSION['player'];
    $_SESSION['moves']++;
    switch (TRUE) {
    case isset($_GET['b1']):
        $_SESSION['board'][0][0] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b2']):
        $_SESSION['board'][0][1] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][1]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b3']):
        $_SESSION['board'][0][2] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][0][1]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][2]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b4']):
        $_SESSION['board'][1][0] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][2]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b5']):
        $_SESSION['board'][1][1] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][1]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][2]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b6']):
        $_SESSION['board'][1][2] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][1][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b7']):
        $_SESSION['board'][2][0] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][0]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][2][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b8']):
        $_SESSION['board'][2][1] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][1]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val)) win();
        break;
    case isset($_GET['b9']):
        $_SESSION['board'][2][2] = $val;
        if (($_SESSION['board'][2][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][2][1]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][2]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][2]==$val) or
            ($_SESSION['board'][0][0]==$val && $_SESSION['board'][1][1]==$val)) win();
        break;
    //default: echo "ERROR: Cannot continue play ?"; exit();
    }
    if ($winner == NOWIN) {
        if ($_SESSION['moves']<9) {
            // swap players
            switch ($_SESSION['player']) {
            case X: $_SESSION['player'] = O; break;
            case O: $_SESSION['player'] = X; break;
            default: echo "ERROR: Cannot switch players ?"; exit();
            }
        } else {
            $msg = "Tie Game!";         
        }
    } else {
        // setup to disable all remaining button/squares in the VIEW
        for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
            for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++)
                if ($_SESSION['board'][$i][$j] == SPACE)
                    $_SESSION['board'][$i][$j] = NOWIN;
    }
}
function win() {
    global $msg;
    global $winner;
    $winner = $_SESSION['player'];
    $msg = $winner . " WINs";
}
?>

<!-- VIEW -->
<html>
<head>
<title>TicTacToe</title>
<style>
body { width:70%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
#board { display:grid; grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; grid-template-rows:auto; 
         border:5px; }
input { height:250px; font-size:5em; border:3px solid black;
        padding:20px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; }
#msg { margin-left:5em; font-size:5em; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="board" name="play" action="hw-ttt.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][0][0]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][0][0]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][0][1]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][0][1]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][0][2]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][0][2]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b4" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][1][0]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][1][0]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][1][1]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][1][1]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b6" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][1][2]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][1][2]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b7" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][2][0]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][2][0]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b8" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][2][1]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][2][1]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="b9" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['board'][2][2]; ?>"
            <?php echo ($_SESSION['board'][2][2]!=" ")?'disabled':''; ?> />
</form>
<form id="replay" name="replay" action="hw-ttt.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Play Again?" />
    <span id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes, this is a homework problem, so I have tried several things.

To give you some faith that I have at least tried this myself, I believe the color change should depend on the `$val` variable, since that is how the `win()` function is triggered. I have tried to figure out how to link `$val` to the `background-color` of `input type="submit"` within the `win()` function, but to no avail.

The best I can do is change the whole board to a color, but it happens on game start and the replay button, regardless of the game state.

Am I at least on the right track?

EDIT:

within the win function I added:

```php
global $wincolor;

$wincolor ="green";
```

and I added to the CSS:

```php
background-color: <?php echo $wincolor ?>
```

which changes the color of EVERY box (including the play again button) so I feel I'm getting closer.

Comment: Reminds me of [a battleship board validation question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545629/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if this was my task, I would completely rewrite the code, but I'll try to amend what you have.

Be sure to implement loops whenever you observe repetition in your code.

You don't need to know "who" won when assessing if a game is finished -- only that it is finished and which tiles won the game.  Use functionless checks in loop structures and return the `b` numbers for future reference.

Then when you are printing your game board, use a loop again and conditionally print any desired attributes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ze4g6))

```
function winningTiles(array $board): array
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
        // check rows
        if ($board[$i][0] !== ' ' && $board[$i][0] === $board[$i][1] && $board[$i][1] === $board[$i][2]) {
            $factor = $i * 3;
            return [$factor + 1, $factor + 2, $factor + 3];
        }
        // check columns
        if ($board[0][$i] !== ' ' && $board[0][$i] === $board[1][$i] && $board[1][$i] === $board[2][$i]) {
            return [$i + 1, $i + 4, $i + 7];
        }
    }
    // check diagonals
    if ($board[0][0] !== ' ' && $board[0][0] === $board[1][1] && $board[1][1] === $board[2][2]) {
        return [1, 5, 9];
    }
    if ($board[0][2] !== ' ' && $board[0][2] === $board[1][1] && $board[1][1] === $board[2][0]) {
        return [3, 5, 7];
    }
    return [];
}

$_SESSION['board'] = [[' ', 'O', 'X'], ['O', 'X', ' '],['X', ' ', ' ']];

$winningTiles = winningTiles($_SESSION['board']);
```

Printing the board:

```
?>
<style>
input {
    height:250px;
    font-size:5em;
    border:3px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.winningTile {
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>
<form id="board" name="play" action="hw-ttt.php" method="get">
    <?php
    foreach ($_SESSION['board'] as $row => $cols) {
        foreach ($cols as $col => $val) {
            $b = $row * 3 + $col + 1;
            printf(
                '<input type="submit" name="b%d" value="%s"%s%s>' . "\n",
                $b,
                $val,
                $val != " " ? ' disabled' : '',
                in_array($b, $winningTiles) ? ' class="winningTile"' : ''
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Output:

```css
#board {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto; 
    border:5px;
}
input {
    height:250px;
    font-size:5em;
    border:3px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.winningTile {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<form id="board" name="play" action="hw-ttt.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value=" ">
    <input type="submit" name="b2" value="O" disabled>
    <input type="submit" name="b3" value="X" disabled class="winningTile">
    <input type="submit" name="b4" value="O" disabled>
    <input type="submit" name="b5" value="X" disabled class="winningTile">
    <input type="submit" name="b6" value=" ">
    <input type="submit" name="b7" value="X" disabled class="winningTile">
    <input type="submit" name="b8" value=" ">
    <input type="submit" name="b9" value=" ">
</form>
```